# How to sync BadgeOS and MyCred in WordPress

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, synchronization

I'm in a position that has to use BadgeOS and MyCred altogether.

In my assumption, each of them has its own point meta_key in the database.

I want to to sync that point meta_key between them. So then, BadgeOS and MyCred have the same total points for each user. In addition, if BadgeOS changes the user's total points to become 98, then MyCred will also determine that the total points of that current user are 98 too and vice-versa.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't directly upload via your providers API, and don't load @uploads, just create an id and the providers url, for the user to view or download in a future scenario.